# Java Exarcise. How to create a class similar to social media site?

Tags: java

Create and implement a class Person.  A Person has a firstName and friends.  Store the names of the friends as a String, separated by spaces.  Provide a constructor that constructs a Person with a given name (passed through arguments) and no friends.  Provide the following methods:

```
public void befriend(Person p)
public void unfriend(Person p)
public String getFriendNames()
public int getFriendCount()
```

*Hint - you can use p.name to access the name of the Person passed to a method as an argument.

Include a Tester class to make sure your Person has some friends.

How do I store the names of the friends as a String, separated by spaces. (I have to be able to input the names from the main method). I also have no idea how to get rid of already inputted name using the method "unfriend"

```
public class Person
{
 private String firstName;
 private String friendNames;
 private int friendCount;

  public Person(String name)
{
    firstName = name;
    friendCount = 0;
}
   public String getFriendNames()
  {
     return friendNames;
  }
     public double getFriendCount()
  {
     return friendCount;
  }
  public void befriend(String name)
{
    friendNames = friendNames + " " + name;
    friendCount++;
}
   public void unfriend(String name)
{
    String[] parseNames = friendNames.split(name);
    friendNames = parseNames[0] + parseNames[1];
    friendCount--;
}

}
```

Main Method:

```
public class PersonTester {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Person p = new Person("Alex");
    p.befriend("John");
    p.befriend("Alice");
    p.befriend("Mike");
    p.befriend("Annette");
    p.unfriend("Alice");

    System.out.println(p.getFriendCount());
    System.out.println(p.getFriendNames());    
  }

}
```

Expected output:

```
2
John Mike
```

Comment: That doesn't look like any JavaScript I've ever seen. Do you mean [tag:java] which is not the same as [tag:javascript]?

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake naming it. I'm new to programming.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt How do I store the names of the friends as a String, separated by spaces. (I have to be able to input the names from the main method). I also have no idea how to get rid of already inputted name by the method "unfriend",

Comment: I would appreciate if people who vote down told me what is wrong with my question so I don't make this mistake again.

Comment: @StarSweeper The first part of my post is the assignment given by my teacher. It says to provide following methods. I tried to base my code on that. However, I don't understand how it is supposed to work and how to use it. So my question is what am I supposed to write there to get expected output.

Comment: Do you have any other class or is it just Person?

Comment: @StarSweeper Right now this is the only class I created for this assignment, I also thought that I might have to create other one to complete it. But in this chapter we stick to creating one class (the object) and the tester class with the main method. So its supposed to be possible to solve it using only one object class.

Comment: So you do have a tester class with a main then?

Comment: I can do it now. I didn't do it because I could not figure out the object so it wouldn't work.

Comment: By the object do you mean person.p?

Comment: @StarSweeper If you have an idea how to write it without referring to person in to last methods that would be good too. Do you know how to store names divided by space?

Comment: @StarSweeper Yes, I called my object Person p, but maybe in the directions (Person p) stands for smth else...

Comment: See my answer, hopefully it clears some things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are having with the methods using the parameter`(Person p)` are because you have two different variables: `friendName` (which exists) and `name` (which does not). Changing the variable `friendName` to `name` will take care of some of the errors you are receiving.

(Also the method `getFriendCount()` returns `friendsCount`, but should return `friendCount` (you have an extra s in there) and your assignment calls for a method called `befriend`, not `bestFriend`.)

How to delete friends:

You can delete a friend by parsing the friend out of the friendNames string and then concatenating the two resulting strings back together:

```
 public void unfriend(String name)
{
    String[] parseNames = friendNames.split(name);
    friendNames = parseNames[0] + parseNames[1];
    friendCount--;
}
```

I would suggest changing befriend and unfriends parameters to accept a String instead of a Person object. Person already has access to its own object and in your main you are trying to pass them Strings anyways. Here is what befriend should look like:

```
 public void befriend(String name) //Changed to "befriend"
{
    friendNames = friendNames + " " + name;
    friendCount++;
}
```

Also, you only need one constructor for Person, which should look like this:

```
 public Person(String name)
{
    firstName = name;
    friendCount = 0;
}
```

When I run your program (using these changes) I get the following output:

```
 2.0
  John  Mike
```

Comment: I'm still playing with it. The firstName is the actual person's name (in the main method I just pasted that is Alex). I don't think that it can be used for friends names.

Comment: Then friendNames needs to be name

Comment: What confuses me, is that you would think your professor would want you to pass a name to befriend and unfriend, but instead you pass the object, which doesn't make any sense since those methods already have access to it

Comment: Oh, I just saw your comment, let me check it out.

Comment: Your program works fine for me when I add the changes I mentioned in my answer. If you still have problems it may be that I forgot something I changed. Let me know.

Comment: Note that friendName should be changed to name (not firstName like I said before)

Comment: Can you send me what you did to bestfriend method?

Comment: Added befriend method and also the reason why I changed the parameters of both befriend and unfriend